# Spatial Join a List of Feature Class Files from Separate Directories

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, spatial-join, feature-class

I am trying to join two lists of feature class files from separate folders into a new folder. I've been successful spatially joining a single file but cannot figure out how to list files from folder 1, files form folder 2 - and then join them together. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
# Import Packages
import arcpy, os, sys, string
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Call the Spatial license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Define the outfolder
outFolder = r"C:\OutFolder"

#Set working environment and list files from folder one
env.workspace = r"C:\Folder1"

#List Files from Folder 1
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for inFeature1 in featureclasses:
    print inFeature1

#Set working environment and list files from folder two
env.workspace = r"C:\Folder2"

#List Files from Folder 2
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for inFeature2 in featureclasses:
    print inFeature2

    #Create file names for the joined file
    outFeature = outFolder + "/" + inFeature2
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(inFeature1, inFeature2, outFeature, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "", "INTERSECT", "", "")
    
print "done"
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Target Features: Dataset 20180201.shp does not exist or is not
> supported Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).

I think the error has something to so with the filenames possible being the same between the two folders. At the very least, I know the ordering of my lists and the application of the function are incorrect.

Any suggestions?

New error after code update:

> Target Features: Dataset \wrrs1\Student Homes\Group
> Projects\TRMM_GPM_Showdown\DiffFiles\Joined Final\20180201.shp does
> not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).

Answer (score 1):

`20180201.shp` is a data set from the folder `r"C:\Folder1"`. After finding this shapefile you change the workspace to `r"C:\Folder2"`. Thus when you reference the variable `inFeature1` in your spatial join python can no longer find the shapefile.

To solve this problem I would use the full path for the shapefile path string in variable `inFeature1`.

Something like this:

```
import os

"""Other code here"""

#Set working environment and list files from folder one
env.workspace = r"C:\Folder1"

#List Files from Folder 1
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for inFeature1 in featureclasses:
    inFeature1 = os.path.join (r"C:\Folder1", inFeature1)
    print inFeature1

"""continue with the rest of the code"""
```

Now python will check the full path and thus the correct folder for `inFeature1`.

Comment: Thanks - I added the code for inFeature one and am getting the same error. I will edit the above post for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: @ Emil. Actually, I made a mistake. I am re-running now and will get back. Thanks for your help.